# Improper use of "Cannot reproduce" closures

Tags: discussion

Ref [Currency converter is not working properly? please help?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/43244/currency-converter-is-not-working-properly-please-help)

This question likely has a pretty clear answer. While there may not be sufficient info to know that the problem is coming from incorrect conversion factor, at the very least a guiding comment would be nice ("Have you set up forex, what's in there now, etc.).

This wasn't even an abandoned question (which is a whole other problem) - it was asked yesterday.